# DinD and AWS Fargate CI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, docker-in-docker

Regarding fargate - since it seems we [can't run containers in privileged mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) and also cannot mount `/var/run/docker.sock`, has anyone figured out a good solution for building/publishing docker images inside fargate tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want AWS Codebuild

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this question after trying to run Jenkins builder slaves in Fargate. Previously they ran in ECS on EC2 instances with the `docker.sock` mounted.
I considered trying DinD but with Fargate currently having the maximum storage size of 10 GB I will abandon this idea for slaves. We would simply want to be able to cache more data before pruning or recycling the slave.

In my opinion storage size is also a factor when considering to build Docker containers in Fargate.